# How periodicaly evaluate the Performance of Models in TF-Slim?

Tags: tensorflow, evaluation, tensorboard, tf-slim

I am trying to use [DensNet](https://github.com/pudae/tensorflow-densenet) for regression problem with TF-Slim. My data contains 60000 jpeg images with 37 float labels for each image. I divided my data into three different tfrecords files of a train set (60%), a validation set (20%) and a test set (20%).

I need to evaluate validation set during training loop and make a plot like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzLPq.jpg). 
In TF-Slim documentation they just explain train loop and evaluation loop separately. I can just evaluate validation or test set after training loop finished. While as I said I need to evaluate during training.

I tried to use slim.evaluation.evaluation_loop function instead of slim.evaluation.evaluate_once. But it doesn't help.

```
slim.evaluation.evaluation_loop(
    master=FLAGS.master,
    checkpoint_dir=checkpoint_path,
    logdir=FLAGS.eval_dir,
    num_evals=num_batches,
    eval_op=list(names_to_updates.values()) + print_ops,
    variables_to_restore=variables_to_restore,
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge(summary_ops),
    eval_interval_secs = eval_interval_secs )
```

I tried evaluation.evaluate_repeatedly as well.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.training.python.training import evaluation

evaluation.evaluate_repeatedly(
    master=FLAGS.master,
    checkpoint_dir=checkpoint_path,
    eval_ops=list(names_to_updates.values()) + print_ops,
    eval_interval_secs = eval_interval_secs )
```

In both of these functions, they just read the latest available checkpoint from checkpoint_dir and apparently waiting for the next one, however when the new checkpoints are generated, they don't perform at all.

I use Python 2.7.13 and Tensorflow 1.3.0 on CPU.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using evaluate_once works just fine with bash script using sleep. Appears that Tensorboard is capable plotting multiple single runs from given eval_dir...

So I use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Paths to model and evaluation results
TRAIN_DIR=~/pDL/tensorflow/model/mobilenet_v1_1_224_rp-v1/run0004
TEST_DIR=${TRAIN_DIR}/eval

# Where the dataset is saved to.
DATASET_DIR=/mnt/data/tensorflow/data

# Run evaluation (using slim.evaluation.evaluate_once)
CONTINUE=1

while [ "$CONTINUE" -ne 0 ]
do

python eval_image_classifier.py \
  --checkpoint_path=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --eval_dir=${TEST_DIR} \
  --dataset_name=master_db \
  --preprocessing_name=preprocess224 \
  --dataset_split_name=valid \
  --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
  --model_name=mobilenet_v1 \
  --patch_size=64

echo "sleeping for next run"
sleep 600
done
```

Comment: Thank you. That is already helpful. I do have the problem that the validation accuracy is not shown in Tensorboard. Or let's phrase it this way: In the first loop I get a single point, in the second loop I only get the validation accuracy of the second loop and after that nothing is shown in Tensorboard anymore. Have you faced the same problem? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

This appear to be issue of setting the checkpoint_path properly as addressed here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13769

Where the answer is by Ellie68 setting:

```
if tf.gfile.IsDirectory(FLAGS.checkpoint_path):
   if tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.checkpoint_path):
       checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.checkpoint_path)
   else:
       checkpoint_path = FLAGS.checkpoint_path
```